# stream стал доступен на Android api 21?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, java-stream

У меня  minSdkVersion == 21

Раньше когда пытался использовать stream, то получал ошибку - нельзя, доступно с версии 24. В подтверждение:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39515035/is-it-possible-to-use-the-java-8-stream-api-on-android-api-24

Приходилось писать  длинные и убогие циклы. Сегодня снова попробовал stream и все заработало!!!

Вопрос: с чего бы это, возможно где-то есть информация о поддержке? Или Android-studio просто затупила показать ошибку и на версиях ниже 24 я буду получать вылеты(у меня нет устройства что бы проверить)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С выходом **Android Studio 3** многое поменялось, но к сожалению для использования стримов все так же необходим `minSdkVersion` как минимум **24**.

Полное описание доступных языковых конструкций и API из Java 8 здесь:
https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#supported_features

Kotlin вам поможет избавиться от длинных и убогих циклов :)

Comment: Интересно, что в одном классе работает в другом нет.... это был тяжелый удар, они дали надежду, а потом забрали..... А вообще это реально что бы они могли добавить поддержку?  Или использовать guava?

Comment: Не думаю что появится, Kotlin же есть и он станет №1 в разработке. Мое личное мнение.